# create html body from outlook command line

Tags: html, command-line, outlook

I am trying to open outlook 2003 with prepopulate data in HTML format.

```
Outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m \"subject=abc&body=<h3>line1</h3>"
```

However the Outlook open new Window without rendering the HTML. My outlook default email is HTML

Any idea?